# Preventing a confirmation pop-up when updating fields in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, macros

In Word 2007, an obvious candidate for updating all the fields in a range is

```
myrange.Fields.Update
```

But if the range is the element of `ActiveDocument.StoryRanges` corresponding to the footnotes, endnotes or comments, this triggers a confirmation pop-up “Word cannot undo this action. Do you want to continue?”

What is this pop-up telling me about? How do I get rid of it (if it's not important)?

An obvious workaround is to iterate over the fields and call each field's `Update` method. It doesn't fire up that question. But if I do this, what do I miss?

<sub>following up to [How do I update all fields in a Word document](https://superuser.com/questions/196703/how-do-i-update-all-fields-in-a-word-document)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any explanation of what can't be undone and it seems that you *can* actually undo these if you have one. It also suggests that setting `Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone` can suppress the error message.